# If $P(X \geq k) = p^k$, for $k=0, 1, 2,...$ then $P(X=k)=p^k(1-p)$

Tags: probability, random-variables

If $P(X \geq  k) = p^k$, for $k=0, 1, 2,...$ then $P(X=k)=p^k(1-p)$

The converse is immediate but I don't know how to approach the direct implication.

Answer (score 3):

HINT:

$$P(X=k) = P(X \geq k) - P(X \geq k+1)$$

Answer (score 3):

$P(X=k) = P(X \ge k) - P(X \ge k+1) = p^k - p^{k+1} = p^k (1-p)$

Comment: Ah ! It should have been obvious. Cheers.